# Please help me how to get data from api with a json body in GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm implementing an autocomplete input with react-select. To load autocomplete options, I need to fetch an API.
I need to do this task on two endpoints, one which is just the URL (this one I got) but this one is different: I need to send a JSON body with the following contents:

> {"searcher" : "VALUE"}

where the value would be the terms that the user would look for, that is, a variable that I attribute to the input.
But I can't do a search and it's not returning anything when I put this code, which is basically the logic I used on the endpoint that only needs the URL. Where am I going wrong?

I have the collection of the API in Postman and I tested it by sending the JSON body and it works, but in the code, no:

```js
export default function PageComponent() {
  const INITIAL_DATA = {
    value: 0,
    label: 'Selecione o Procedimento',
  };

  const [selectData, setselectData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA);
  const mapResponseToValuesAndLabels = (data) => ({
    value: data.id,
    label: data.terminologia,
  });

 async function callApi(value) {

 
     /* var data = JSON.stringify({
      "buscador": "CAP"
    }); */
    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: `http://devsite.redetelemedicabr.com.br:3333/medsigtap/byTerminologia`,
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept' : '*/*'
        
      },
      data :JSON.stringify({
        "buscador": "CAP"
      })

    })

    
      api.get('/').then(res => {
        console.log(res.data,'fefe')
      })
     
  
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        loadOptions={callApi}
        onChange={(data) => {
          setselectData(data);
        }}
        value={selectData}
        defaultOptions
      />
```

In this code, I need to get the response from API and map it to have a label and value so it can show it on the autocomplete options.

I'm getting on response log only an empty array `[]`
but in postman it works, I received what I'm looking for (the CAP objs ).

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"Write a title that summarizes **the specific problem**"_

Comment: Don't expose true urls, since someone can use it to extract information, that can be confidential. Maybe on your url you don't have nothing confidential, but be carefully.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are not sending the data correctly

send the jsonData like this:

```
const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
});

const response = rawResponse.json().map(mapResponseToValuesAndLabels);
```

Comment: also it's always good to separate your api calls into another file
i usually name the files provider or service

Comment: the only method that this endpoint accepts is GET